# What is just "LDA" in GPAW?

Tags: exchange-correlation, gpaw, libxc

When using GPAW with the option `xc='LDA'`, which of the potentials in https://tddft.org/programs/libxc/functionals/ is used ? Or which combination of them? Is it "LDA_X" or or one of the "LDA_XC" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [GPAW's documentation](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/documentation/basic.html#exchange-correlation-functional), GPAW would use its own LDA implementation, but if I interpret the table correctly, that should correspond to libxc's LDA_X + LDA_C_PW:

> ### Exchange-Correlation functional
>
> Some of the most commonly used exchange-correlation functionals are listed below.
>
> | `xc` | full libxc keyword | description | reference |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | `LDA` | `LDA_X+LDA_C_PW` | Local density approximation | 1 |
> | `PBE` | `GGA_X_PBE+GGA_C_PBE` | Perdew, Burke, Ernzerhof | 2 |
> | `revPBE` | `GGA_X_PBE_R+GGA_C_PBE` | revised PBE | 3 |
> | `RPBE` | `GGA_X_RPBE+GGA_C_PBE` | revised revPBE | 4 |
> | `PBE0` | `HYB_GGA_XC_PBEH` | Known as PBE0 | 5 |
> | `B3LYP` | `HYB_GGA_XC_B3LYP` | B3LYP (as in Gaussian Inc.) | 6 |
>
> `LDA` is the default value. The next three ones are of generalized gradient approximation (GGA) type, and the last two are [hybrid functionals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_functional).
>
> For the list of all functionals available in GPAW see [Exchange-correlation functionals module](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/devel/overview.html#overview-xc).
>
> **GPAW uses the functionals from [libxc](https://tddft.org/programs/libxc/) by default (except for LDA, PBE, revPBE, RPBE and PW91 where GPAW’s own implementation is used).**

(The last sentence is bolded by me for emphasis.)